# Download Unity app from phone back to computer

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

My MacBook was stolen which had all my Unity apps I was working on saved on it. Beforehand, I had downloaded some of those apps onto my iPhone 5s for testing through Xcode 7 and I still have the phone. I was wondering if there was any way to get the apps on my phone back onto a different mac into Unity to be edited, re-downloaded etc.

Comment: But even if it is possible, there is no source code of your apps on iPhone. What would you do with out of it? It is aways better to store code on some external repository (like github) for such cases

Comment: But the apps on my phone run indepedently from my mac so there must be code stored on the phone. The app was downloaded through the new xcode7 beta feature where you can download the app onto your phone for testing, but you don't need a mac for it to run once its downloaded. @user996142

Comment: I wish that were possible but I'm a beginner at this so I don't think I knowingly backed it up in any way but do you know how I could check that? Thanks

Comment: Best you can do is record everything on your phone with a camera or another phone and save as much detail of the application as possible to recreate it or have proof that it existed. Reverse engineering it back to code will take more time and skill than to build them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity builds are heavily obfuscated to prevent users extracting assets including your code. There have been some efforts to reverse engineer some of the assets but the source code is compiled to byte-code so you won't be able to recover a "clean" version of your original.
You probably want to set up a source control and make backups next time.

Comment: I'm clearly not an expert regarding this but I found this website: http://www.pyromuffin.com/2013/10/reverse-engineering-unity-games.html  and http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/520699/is-there-any-way-to-get-script-from-compiled-game.html does this sound plausible? @Josep Valls

Comment: As it states in the links you already found, you can extract some assets and decompile part of the code but you will not get comments or local variables. Also, bear in mind that both those responses are from 2 years ago. Since then, Unity has changed a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any way I could have saved it unwillingly to time machine or icloud and if so how would I check that. Thanks again. @Josep Valls

Comment: I am not familiar with Time machine but if you have it enabled it may be saved there. You may want to ask on http://apple.stackexchange.com